restricted_image_training_cpus exhausted error but peak usage at 19% on GCP Vertex AutoML
I am running a Vertex AutoML model on GCP (free account).
I have done 6 attempts/runs, but that they all failed so far. My latest error in the logs says
"The following quota metrics exceed quota limits: aiplatform.googleapis.com/restricted_image_training_cpus"google3.third_party.py.cloud_ml_autoflow.util_lib.error.PublicError: error code: 8".
However, i look at the usage for restricted_image_training_cpus only goes to 8; my quota should allow 42 (default setting). Peak usage in last 7 days is 19,05%.
So i don't understand why GCP is giving me this error or what i should do.
In tab Configurations: Quota for service CPUs for my location is at 16 out of 24, so 66,67% which seems ok
I was able to reproduce this error and have taken screenshots.
I ve read post below and similar ones, but they don't seem to apply as my threshold do not seem to be hit. https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Vertex-AI-tunning-chat-bison-exceeded-quota-exception/...  Anyhow, i am on free account so i can t request quota increase anyhow.
I have enabled the Quota Adjuster but i keep running into the same error
